# Activity monitoring

Tags: activity

I want to use Civi to monitor support time organisations have bought from us. Ideally for Civi to alert me when organisations are in the negative and need to purchase more support time? whats would be the best functions to get this info ?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit of software out there that does time-tracking already. For example - I use https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/ - I can run time reports that show me how many hours an organization has left in their IT bundle at any time.

That's certainly not the only one out there - Other CiviCRM partnes use many other time tracking software instances but I don't know anyone who does this in CiviCRM.